# select html table cell based on cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery

grvData is the table name and .tabulator-col-title is the div which holds the Column name. I get zero when I use the below jquery code to get the index of the column .tabulator-headers div. Please suggest me how do I know the index of .tabulator-col-title class in .tabulator-headers class.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            
            alert($(".tabulator-col-title:contains('Rent')").index());
        });
```

```html
<div cellspacing="0" id="grvData" style="border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;" class="tabulator" role="grid" tabulator-layout="fitDataFill">
    <div class="tabulator-header" style="padding-right: 0px;">
        <div class="tabulator-headers" style="margin-left: 0px;">
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="id" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 86px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">ID</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="purpose" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 103px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Purpose</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="rent" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 67px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Rent</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="total_rent" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 101px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Total Rent</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
         
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="discount" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 94px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Discount</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="months" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 83px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Months</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabulator-col tabulator-sortable" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="building" title="" style="min-width: 40px; height: 29px; width: 273px;">
                <div class="tabulator-col-content">
                    <div class="tabulator-col-title-holder">
                        <div class="tabulator-col-title">Building</div>
                        <div class="tabulator-col-sorter">
                            <div class="tabulator-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
                <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
            </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="tabulator-frozen-rows-holder"></div>
    </div>
   
</div>
```

ID
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                
                    
                        Purpose
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
            
            
                
                    
                        Rent
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
            
            
                
                    
                        Total Rent
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
         
            
                
                    
                        Discount
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                
                    
                        Months
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                
            
            
                
                    
                        Building

Comment: you can but an easier way is to use css class. for each rent td give them class of myrent and then use jquery to select it

Comment: so `Rent` is a vlaue inside the table? can you give an example on how the table looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get index value of the `th` and then just use `td:eq("indexvalueofth")` to get required values.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var indexs =$("thead  th:contains('Rent')").index();//get index of th 
console.log($("tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq("+indexs+") ").text());//pass it inside `eq()`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Rent</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>1233</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am using the below code and I get zero all the time
alert($(".tabulator-col-title:contains(Rent)").index());

however it gives me correct length of this particular class occerance
    alert($(".tabulator-col-title").length);

Comment: I edited my question and added html code. grvData is the table name and 'tabulator-col-title' is the class where column name is placed.
I am using the below code and it gives me zero
alert($("#grvData .tabulator-col-title:contains('Rent')").index());

Comment: Hi, try like this : `console.log($("div.tabulator-col-title:contains('Rent')").closest(".tabulator-col").index());`

Comment: Yuhuu, got it. Thanks swati.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`:contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) makes this quite easy

```js
$('tr:first td:contains("Rent")').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Rent</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Rent</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```